Invoke-SShCommand to SNR Switch
Хочу с коммутатора SNR вытащить часть конфига через ssh сессию.
Вот часть кода:
$SSHSession = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $SwitchIP -Credentials $Credentials -AcceptKey #Устанавливается соединение
$OsVersion = Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionID $SSHSession.SessionId -Command 'show version' #Отправка команды.

На этапе отправки команды, получаю ошибку:
        Исключение при вызове "BeginExecute" с "0" аргументами: "Failed to open a channel after 10 attempts."
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Posh-SSH\3.2.1\Posh-SSH.psm1:377 знак:17
+                 $Async = $cmd.BeginExecute()
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SshException

Пробовал таким образом:
$SSHStream = $SSHSession.Session.CreateShellStream('dumb', 80, 24, 800, 600, 1000)

Но ошибка вот такая:
    Исключение при вызове "CreateShellStream" с "6" аргументами: "Failed to open a channel after 10 attempts."
строка:1 знак:1
+ $SSHSession.Session.CreateShellStream('dumb', 80, 24, 800, 600, 1000)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SshException

Не понимаю в какую сторону смотреть, где собака зарыта?
P.S. Версия модуля Posh-SSH - 3.2.1

Добавьте -Verbose. Кстати, вы пытались подключиться просто ssh клиентом?

Да, просто ssh клиентом (putty) подключается. Командлет New-SSHSession - тоже говорит что сессия установлена.

С -Verbose тоже самое. У ошибки "BeginExecute" есть продолжение:

Исключение при вызове "EndExecute" с "1" аргументами: "Значение не может быть неопределенным.
Имя параметра: asyncResult"
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Posh-SSH\3.2.1\Posh-SSH.psm1:294 знак:25


                    $Output = $_.cmd.EndExecute($_.Async)



                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException




Судя по вот этому багу - https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/305, подробностей вы от библиотеки не дождётесь. Тут только ставить студию (если её ещё нет), скачивать исходники библиотеки и отлаживать.
